# no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input#btnshow"}

Tags: java, css, selenium, automation, webdriverwait

I am a beginner in selenium, I am using java for that, I am getting a error saying Unable to locate element although that element is present in the web page.

Java Code:

```
    WebDriver dChromedriver=new ChromeDriver();
    dChromedriver.get("https://erp.mitwpu.edu.in/");
    dChromedriver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement  txtPassword=dChromedriver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")) ;
    WebElement txtUserId=dChromedriver.findElement(By.id("txtUserId")) ;
    txtUserId.sendKeys("S1032200787");
    txtPassword.sendKeys("FynS@3XbZH6ZMWH");
        //
        WebDriverWait w =new WebDriverWait(dChromedriver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
         
 
 w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='ReCaptchContainer']")));
        dChromedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ReCaptchContainer']")).click();
//      Thread.sleep(3000);
        w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("label#lblMessage")));
        WebElement success_lablElement=dChromedriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label#lblMessage"));
        Assert.assertEquals(success_lablElement.getText(),"Success" );
        dChromedriver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
        WebElement resultWebElement=dChromedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@class=\"mt-2\"]/ul/li[12]/a[@href=\"Examination/Report/StudentGradeCardDetail.aspx?MENU_CODE=Web_Result\"]"));
        resultWebElement.click();
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    dChromedriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#btnshow")).click();
```

html code:

```
 <div class="labelinfo col-md-12 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 padd6">                                  <input type="submit" name="btnshow" value="Show" onclick="return funValidation();" id="btnshow" class="btn btn-primary" style=""> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="submit" value="Show" onclick="return funValidation();" id="btnshow" class="btn btn-primary" style="">
```

> 

```
 </div>
```

Comment: We'd need to see the rest of your HTML to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The element `Show` button is inside an `iframe`.
In order to access the element, you need to switch to `iframe` first and then you can access the element.

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()` and wit for `elementtobeclickable()` to click on the `Show` button.

```
WebDriverWait w =new WebDriverWait(dChromedriver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));

w.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("FrameContent")));

w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnshow"))).click();
```

To jump out from `iframe` you need to use this code.

```
dChromedriver.switchto().defaultcontent();
```

Snapshot iframe:

[image]